# Are these depth-41 Stockfish evals the result of a horizon effect?

Tags: analysis, stockfish, french-defense

I was using lichess's analysis board for Stockfish's analysis of this line in the French:

```
[Title "French Defence, Steinitz Variation"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen ""]

1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e5 Nfd7 5. f4 c5 6. Nf3 Nc6 7. Be3 Qb6 8. Na4
```

Seeing as this is a familiar line, lichess already had Stockfish analysis to a deep level available in the cloud. After 7 Be3 is played in lichess, it says Stockfish (depth 41) rates 7 ... Qb6 at 0.0,
giving the line 8 a3 cxd4 9 Nxd4 Bc5 10 Na4 Qa5+ 11 Nc3.
But if 7 ... Qb6 is then played in lichess, it says Stockfish rates 8 Na4 as +0.6.

That's a difference of 0.6. That's much greater than rounding error. How come such a large difference? Could it be a horizon effect? If so, it's a particularly distant one! I'd have thought that analysing to depth 41 would give Stockfish plenty of opportunity to reach a quiescent position.

Comment: Did you note that once Qb6 is on the board, depth is 47 plies?

Comment: Maybe i just do not understand the question. `But if 7 ... Qb6 is then played in lichess, it says Stockfish rates 8 Na4 as +0.6.` -> what is depth for this analyse? I am not near my Stockfish engine but difference 0.6 in the opening (7th move) is not that high imho.